# curl syntax for PostgREST query

Tags: postgrest

Using PostgREST (http://postgrest.org/en/v5.2/api.html) version 5.2 against a Postgres 11 database, the following curl command:

```
curl -X GET http://192.18.11.13:5741/workorder?acctid=eq.SunnySide&workorderid=eq.0001
```

generates the following trace in the Postgres log:

```
SELECT "public"."workorder".* FROM "public"."workorder"  WHERE  "public"."workorder"."acctid" = 'SunnySide'::unknown
```

The "restriction" of workorderid=eq.0001 in the original query is dropped so the data returned includes all 'SunnySide' matches and not the single 0001 workorderid as desired.

What is the correct syntax of this command in curl so that workorderid is also passed to the Postgres server?

Answer (score 4):

You need to quote(`""`) the url. Like:

```bash
curl "http://192.18.11.13:5741/workorderacctid=eq.SunnySide&workorderid=eq.0001"
```

Otherwise your shell will treat the command after the `&` symbol as a background process. That's why `workorderid=eq.0001` doesn't get included in the `curl` call. It's actually being interpreted as a separate command(variable assignment).

Comment: I would even recommend single quotes to ensure the shell interprets nothing at all. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash